# determining the zoom level to show polygons on google map

Tags: algorithm, google-maps-api-3

I am showing some review data clustered by state, county, city level on the US map. Initially map is shown to show all the states with number pointer showing the number reviews available for the state. Clicking on the state opens the county level. Clicking the county opens up the city level clusters and eventually clicking the city opens the individual google markers. This works fine.

The issue I am having is with zooming in and zooming out. I want to way to determine at what level to break a state on county, county into city, city into markers based on the zoom level of the google map. I cannot use static levels of zooming cause the area of the polygon varies e.g. Texas is much bigger than Rhode Island.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the geocoder.  It returns a suggested viewport for the state, county or city

```
function findAddress(address) {
  if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          if (results && results[0]
              && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport) 
            mapfitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: trying this out now.. will let you know if this works (sounds like a good approach but I may hit google's geocoder limits once I reach the city level data)

Comment: Why would you need to query so quickly at the city level?  I would have thought that would have been operator controlled.